# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger in a Java project

Tags: java, selenium, log4j, testng, rest-assured

I have created a java project and added log4j library, and log4j.xml in source folder.I have intialized it properly but i am getting error as log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.restassured.tests.tokenAuthorization).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
code

```
    package com.restassured.tests;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.restassured.restcalls.RestCalls;
import com.restassured.utils.PayloadConverterToString;
import com.restassured.utils.URL;

import io.restassured.response.Response;

public class tokenAuthorization {

    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(tokenAuthorization.class.getName());

    Response response;

    @Test
    public void getToken() throws IOException {

        log.info("Invoking request of getToken");

        String uri = URL.getResource("/oauth2/token");
        String payload = PayloadConverterToString.generatePayloadString("TokenPayload.txt");
        response = RestCalls.callPost(uri, payload);
        String strResponse = response.getBody().asString();

        log.info("response =" + strResponse);


    }

}
```

response

```
    [TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\mp00467722\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--2081056548\testng-customsuite.xml

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.restassured.tests.tokenAuthorization).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
PASSED: getToken

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@49e4cb85: 13 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter@1d251891: 5 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [TestListenerAdapter] Passed:0 Failed:0 Skipped:0]: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1cd072a9: 13 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@75bd9247: 80 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@2c8d66b2: 55 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like either your log4j.xml is not proper or it's not placed at right location. Try adding it in src/test/resources directory as well.